# Finding text, excluding supersets in Sublime

Tags: search, find, sublimetext2

I remember hearing about the option to search for an exact word in Sublime, but I can't seem to find it.

What I mean by this is if I search for `write`, I'd like to exclude all instances of `foo_write`, `foowrite`, etc.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> (Win/Lin) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> (OS X) to open up the Find tab. Make sure the first button on the left (Regular Expressions) is selected. In the search field, enter `\bfoo\b` and click the <kbd>Find</kbd> button or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to search. The `\b` token indicates a word boundary, including spaces, punctuation marks like commas, periods/full stops, question marks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the third button from the left, a pair of double quotes, says 'Whole Word' when you hover - Click this to find the exact word.

E.g., if I search for 'stage' it will return the line that contains the text 'when the stage changes' but not the line that contains the text '= b.stage__c'